# Called Arcpy Script doesn't finish if called from C# Console App

Tags: python, c#, esri, arcpy

Good Morning StackOverflowers,

There is another problem i cant solve without your help. I am working on a C# Console App (.NET 5) which is calling different Python Scripts to do ArcGis Stuff (=> "arcpy"-Lib :). The Scheme of calling them is always the same and there was never a problem. In the course of penetration tests i discovered an issue by one of the scripts:

The following script "foreaches" every row in the featureclass, zooms to it and exports it as an .png-File.

Executing this via a cmd (Non Admin & Admin) or via Python Gui (available with ArcGis Setup) it's works perfectly (=> creating 138 images), BUT if i execute it via C# App, it only creates 36 images, after that the process continues running but without creating images. The CPU Usage drops from 12% to 0% after creating the 36th images.

The second code snippet shows the called method but also describes the scheme of calling my python scripts. I am very much aware of the fact that this is not written well and i am going to do some code polish after fixing this problem :)

I hope there is someone out there with a tip.

Thank you very much in advance.
Kind regards,
Jan

```
import arcpy,os, logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='appPython.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

#Static Variables
mxdfileName = "D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\Templates\TemplateTelematik.mxd"

# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses
arcpy.env.workspace = str(sys.argv[1])
#arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\DigFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte.gdb"

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

try:
    
    # Copy shapefiles to a file geodatabase
    for fc in featureclasses:
        featureName = os.path.splitext(fc)[0]
        if "Dienstverrichtung_" in featureName and "_Projection" in featureName:
            print(featureName)

            #Global Variables
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdfileName)
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            #Create FeatureLayer
            SelectionLayer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(fc, "SelectionLayer").getOutput(0)

            #Add Layer to mxd
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, SelectionLayer, "TOP")

            #Refresh TOC and DataFrames
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            #Refresh TOC and DataFrames
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            feature = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, SelectionLayer, df)[0]

            fields = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', 'Name']
            pngPath = r"D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\Images"

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature, fields) as cursor:
                for FID, Geometry, Name in cursor:
                    mxd.title = Name
                    print("{} in Bearbeitung.".format(mxd.title))
                    query = "ObjectID = {}".format(str(FID))
                    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(feature, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
          
                    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
                    df.scale=2500
                    df.referenceScale = 3500
                    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
       
                    png = "{}\\{}.png".format(pngPath, Name)
        
                    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, png, df, df_export_width=2200, df_export_height=1300)
                    print("{} erfolgreich exportiert.".format(mxd.title))

    print("Script beendet")

except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info = True)
```

```
public static async Task<Tuple<string, bool>> ZoomToSelectedFeatures(string pPathToPythonExe, string pPathGeoDatabase)
        {
            Tuple<string, bool> resultTuple = null;
            StringBuilder scriptMessageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            string scriptExceptions = string.Empty;
            string scriptPrints = string.Empty;
            string pythonPath = @"C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.8/python.exe";

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(delegate
                {
                    if (pPathToPythonExe != "")
                    {
                        pythonPath = pPathToPythonExe;
                    }

                    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    //python interprater location
                    start.FileName = pythonPath;
                    //argument with file name and input parameters
                    start.Arguments =
                        $"{Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Python_Scripts\\Batch_ZoomToSelectedFeaturesAndExportPNG_2.py")}" +
                        $" {pPathGeoDatabase}";

                    start.UseShellExecute = false; // Do not use OS shell
                    start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
                    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
                    start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
                    start.LoadUserProfile = true;

                    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                    {
                        process.WaitForExit();

                        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                        {
                            scriptExceptions = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                            scriptPrints = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                            Debug.WriteLine("Batch_ZoomToSelectedFeaturesAndExportPNG_2.py meldet:");
                            Debug.WriteLine(scriptPrints);
                            Debug.WriteLine(scriptExceptions);
                            scriptMessageBuilder.AppendLine(scriptPrints);
                            scriptMessageBuilder.AppendLine(scriptExceptions);
                        }
                    }

                    resultTuple = new Tuple<string, bool>(scriptMessageBuilder.ToString(), true);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                Debug.WriteLine(scriptExceptions);
                resultTuple = new Tuple<string, bool>(scriptMessageBuilder.ToString(), false);
            }

            return resultTuple;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by changing the output from "print messages" to "log entries". Now.... i honestly dont know why, the script creates all images correctly. Below the edited script.

Thanks anyway, Have a nice day!

```
import arcpy,os,logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # process everything, even if everything isn't printed
fh = logging.FileHandler('D:\\appPython.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or any level you want
logger.addHandler(fh)

#Define Variables
#Static Variables
mxdfileName = "D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\Templates\TemplateTelematik.mxd"

# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses
arcpy.env.workspace = str(sys.argv[1])
#arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\DigFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte.gdb"

# Use the ListFeatureClasses function to return a list of
#  shapefiles.
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


try:
    # Copy shapefiles to a file geodatabase
    for fc in featureclasses:
        featureName = os.path.splitext(fc)[0]
        if "Dienstverrichtung_" in featureName and "_Projection" in featureName:
            logger.info(featureName)

            #Global Variables
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdfileName)
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            #Create FeatureLayer
            SelectionLayer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(fc, "SelectionLayer").getOutput(0)

            #Add Layer to mxd
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, SelectionLayer, "TOP")

            #Refresh TOC and DataFrames
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            #Refresh TOC and DataFrames
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

            feature = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, SelectionLayer, df)[0]

            fields = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', 'Name']
            pngPath = r"D:\DigitalesFahrtenbuch_Datenpunkte\Images"

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature, fields) as cursor:
                for FID, Geometry, Name in cursor:
                    mxd.title = Name
                    
                    #print("{} in Bearbeitung.".format(mxd.title))
                    logger.info("{} in Bearbeitung.".format(mxd.title))

                    query = "ObjectID = {}".format(str(FID))
                    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(feature, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
          
                    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
                    df.scale=2500
                    df.referenceScale = 3500
                    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
       
                    png = "{}\\{}.png".format(pngPath, Name)
        
                    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, png, df, df_export_width=2200, df_export_height=1300)
                    
                    logger.info("{} erfolgreich exportiert.".format(mxd.title))
                    #print("{} erfolgreich exportiert.".format(mxd.title))
    logger.info("Script beendet")

except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
```